# Foundation - 5 iPhone 6 website being shown in desktop version

Tags: ios, media-queries, responsive, iphone-6, zurb-foundation-5

I am building a website using Foundation 5, however when viewed on iPhone 6 or 6+ it shows the desktop version and that's easy to understand.

However what is the best way/best practice to stick to a mobile view as if it was for (iPhone 4 or 5)?

Comment: Does it show the desktop version in both landscape and portrait on iPhone 6/6+? And what do you mean by that's easy to understand?

Comment: Easy to understand because of the pixel density... I meant I know why it odes that, I was wondering if foundation came up with some best practice to cater for it or some sort of workaround...

Comment: Gotcha. Hope my answer worked for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Foundation Sass, go to the settings file and uncomment the line in the media query section that reads:

```
// $small-range: (0em, 40em)
```

The iPhone 6 screen is 23.4383em x 41.688em, and the iPhone 6 Plus screen is 25.875em x 46.125em. If you change `$small-range` to go higher than 46.125em it should keep it at mobile view on those iPhones.